# how to create a function parameter that won't be copied and cannot be null

Tags: go

In golang, Is it possible to create a function that takes a struct with the following constraints:

- the struct must not be copied (its relatively big)
- the caller must not be able to pass `nil`

EDIT:
I tried using pointers but that can be set to null. I can't find any good articles on how to use references and it doesn't seem like I can pass by reference.

Comment: No. But that is too short as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create tiny struct wrapper which holds private pointer to big struct and defines `Get` method to allow acquisition of this big struct. Inside `Get` you check if pointer is nil then it panics.

Something like:

```
type StructHolder struct {
    target *BigStruct
}

func (s StructHolder) Get() *BigStruct {
    if s.target == nil {
        panic("target is nil")
    }

    return s.target
}
```

Why would you do this? I'd think its better to pass a pointer and check its value.

Comment: that's what I ended up doing. I just didn't want another check in my function because its hard to read already.